# RecyclerView select multi item when user select single item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I create recycler view and inflate it many elements like text view and image view the problem is when user press on any one position to bookmark it the item selected good but I found that there another item bookmarked automatic what the problem.

Here is a code

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  Get_Set_Note movie=moviesList.get(position); 
  holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle()); 
  holder.time.setText(movie.getTime());

  holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       @Override public void onClick(View v) { 

       holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_big_on); 
     }
  });
}
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bg2T3krPedlC6ue_sldk4X8zyW675EzV/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Create an on-site [mcve] - don't use external services to show the code.

Comment: have you created ? boolean value in your data model ? which you are using for fill and in fill star ?

Comment: public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Get_Set_Note movie=moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.time.setText(movie.getTime());

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
            }
        });

Comment: Upper code when click any recycler view item to bookmarked it.but it bookmark multi item.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Im sorry mister Mike M. Im new with overflow stack and not complete with its rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can solve it

You need to add to your `Get_Set_Note` one boolean property `isFavorite`

Like this

**Get_Set_Note.java**

```
Boolean isFavorite = false
```

And simply in your adapter set your star image base on this condition

```
if(movie.isFavorite){
   holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_big_on); 
 }else{
  holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_big_off); 
}
```

And on Click listener you can set you boolean property and notify the adapter

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       @Override public void onClick(View v) {
         if(movie.isFavorite){ 
              movie.isFavorite = false
         }else{
             movie.isFavorite = true  
         }
          notifyDataSetChanged()
     }
});
```

And then finally your `bindViewHolder` would be like this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  Get_Set_Note movie=moviesList.get(position); 
  holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle()); 
  holder.time.setText(movie.getTime());

  if(movie.isFavorite){
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_big_on); 
  }else{
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_star_big_off); 
  }

  holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
       @Override public void onClick(View v) {
         if(movie.isFavorite){ 
              movie.isFavorite = false
         }else{
             movie.isFavorite = true  
         }
          notifyDataSetChanged()
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arbaz Pirwani

Comment: My pleasure pal 